# correct use of them

Tags: sentence-construction

Them is used to refer to an object. In the following sentence

> [Yisrael Beiteinu leader Avigdor Lieberman, a former Netanyahu aide, has submitted ***a bill*** to the Knesset that would enable the government to draft ***them***.](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/a-second-election/article27394438.ece)

**Them** is used to refer to a bill but **bill** is singular here. I am confused about this.

Comment: Read it again, they're not talking about the bill when they use "them".

Comment: I have read it several times and tried to access the original on the HIndu (which requires readers to remove ad-blockers). But I agree with the OP that **it** is required, unless **them** refers back to a **plural**, such as **clauses**, used earlier in the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ultra-orthodox Jews, the Haredim, are exempt from mandatory military service. Yisrael Beiteinu leader Avigdor Lieberman, a former Netanyahu aide, has submitted a bill to the Knesset that would enable the government to draft them.

Them refers to the Haredim which is a plurality.